# Vue project - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetWidth') error for a custom js script

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

so I'm converting a custom html template to a vuejs project.
I've imported all css and js files to be used in my homepage. Css files are loading fine.
For JS files, the theme came with a few custom js scripts along with usual libraries like three.js etc.
I'm importing all of them below my HomeComponent in the script tag.
But I run into this error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetWidth')
    at eval (demo3.js?dad6:2:20)
    at ./src/assets/assets/js/demo3.js (app.js:92:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1124:33)
    at fn (app.js:1357:21)
    at eval (index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/HomeComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:26:85)
    at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/HomeComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:30:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1124:33)
    at fn (app.js:1357:21)
    at eval (HomeComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:5:216)
    at ./src/components/HomeComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:296:1)"
```

Below is my App.vue code:

```html
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
};
</script>
```

Below is my homecomponent.vue code (partial - some code hidden from inside template):

```js
<template>
  <header class="offcanvas-menu">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toogle-menu" />

    <label for="toogle-menu" class="toogle-open"><span></span></label>

    <nav>
      <div>
        <label for="toogle-menu" class="toogle-close">
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">Section </a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section </a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section </a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Section </a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Section </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="content">
      <canvas class="scene scene--full" id="scene"></canvas>
      <div class="content__inner">
        <h2 class="content__title">مؤشر المعلوماتية</h2>
        <div class="content-button mt-2">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-relief-primary btn-large menu-trigger display-5"
          >
            <i data-feather="menu"></i> القائمة
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="grim">
      <div class="grim__item">
        <div class="grim__item-bg grim__item-bg--5"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grim__item">
        <div class="grim__item-bg grim__item-bg--5"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grim__item">
        <div class="grim__item-bg grim__item-bg--5"></div>
        <div class="grim__item-content">
          <div class="grim__item-inner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  ..
   
    
      <div class="grim__item">
        <div class="grim__item-bg grim__item-bg--9"></div>
        <div class="grim__item-img grim__item-img--4"></div>
        <a href="dashboard-region.html" class="grim__link grim__item-content">
          <div class="grim__item-inner">
            <h3 class="grim__item-title">test</h3>
            <span class="grim__item-desc">test</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="grim__item-bg grim__item-bg-cover grim__item-bg--9"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grim__item">
        <div class="grim__item-bg grim__item-bg--10"></div>
        <div class="grim__item-img grim__item-img--5" style=""></div>
        <a href="wizard.html" class="grim__link grim__item-content">
          <div class="grim__item-inner">
            <h3 class="grim__item-title">test</h3>
            <span class="grim__item-desc"
              >test</span
            >
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="grim__item-bg grim__item-bg-cover grim__item-bg--10"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </main>
  <!-- home -->
</template>
<style>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow:400,500,700|Poppins:600");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400;1,500;1,600");
</style>
<script>
//All css files
import "../assets/assets/css/base.css";

import "../assets/app-assets/css-rtl/bootstrap.css";
import "../assets/app-assets/css-rtl/bootstrap-extended.css";
import "../assets/app-assets/css-rtl/colors.css";
import "../assets/app-assets/css-rtl/themes/dark-layout.css";
import "../assets/assets/css/menu.css";

import "../assets/app-assets/css-rtl/custom-rtl.css";
import "../assets/assets/css/style-rtl.css";

export default {
  name: "HomeComponent",
};

//All JS files
import "../assets/assets/js/demo.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/three.min.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/perlin.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/TweenMax.min.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/demo3.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/grid.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/anime.min.js";
import "../assets/assets/js/menu2.js";
</script>
```

The issue is with the demo3.js file.

Demo3.js

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#scene");
var width = canvas.offsetWidth,
  height = canvas.offsetHeight;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 2 : 1);
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.setClearColor(0x161d31);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(120, 0, 300);

var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x0c056d, 0.6);
scene.add(light);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x590d82, 0.5);
light.position.set(100, 300, 400);
scene.add(light);
var light2 = light.clone();
light2.position.set(-100, 300, 400);
scene.add(light2);

var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(120, 4);
for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
  var vector = geometry.vertices[i];
  vector._o = vector.clone();
}
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  emissive: 0x23f660,
  emissiveIntensity: 0.4,
  shininess: 0,
});
var shape = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(shape);

function updateVertices(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    var vector = geometry.vertices[i];
    vector.copy(vector._o);
    var perlin = noise.simplex3(
      vector.x * 0.006 + a * 0.0002,
      vector.y * 0.006 + a * 0.0003,
      vector.z * 0.006
    );
    var ratio = perlin * 0.4 * (mouse.y + 0.3) + 0.9;
    vector.multiplyScalar(ratio);
  }
  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}

function render(a) {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  updateVertices(a);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onResize() {
  canvas.style.width = "";
  canvas.style.height = "";
  width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(0.8, 0.5);
function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to(mouse, 0.8, {
    y: e.clientY / height,
    x: e.clientX / width,
    ease: Power1.easeOut,
  });
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
var resizeTm;
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  resizeTm = clearTimeout(resizeTm);
  resizeTm = setTimeout(onResize, 200);
});
```

So, my app is not loading at all. now I'm lost how to resolve this. This is my first time converting html template to vuejs. Idk what to expect.
Screenshot of file scructure
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKzTb.png)

screenshot of error details in console.log
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rzap.png)

Comment: In demo3.js 
this line gives you a null object
var canvas = document.querySelector("#scene");
So your canvas = null and you cant access offsetWidth

Comment: @Legit007 how to fix it ? I understand it does, I must mount the dom somehow before js is loaded but idk how

Comment: Maybe you can try using async mounted on your export default:
https://lavalite.org/blog/created-and-mountedin-vuejs

and call your js in the mounted block

Comment: didn't work :( @Legit007

Comment: So you called your js function in your mounted function and still get null with document.querySelector("#scene")?
You need to add the mounted function to the homecomponent.vue
You should than not import 'import "../assets/assets/js/demo3.js"; you need to import the function.  Like -> import { yourFunction } from "demo3.js";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing your `demo3.js` file (and thus executing it) before the app rendered the DOM. So the element `#scene` doesn't exist yet, resulting in being `null`.

Several solutions for this:

1. You import dynamically your `demo3.js` file after `mounted` hook:

```js
mounted() {
  import('../assets/assets/js/demo3.js') // dynamic import
}
```

2. You wrap your `demo3.js` code inside a function and export it.

```js
// demo3.js

export function renderScene() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#scene");
  var width = canvas.offsetWidth,
    height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  // [...]
}
```

```js
import { renderScene } from '../assets/assets/js/demo3.js'

export default {
  mounted() {
    renderScene()
  }
}
```

3. You move your `demo3.js` code to a vue component, and use template refs.

```js
mounted() {
  const scene = this.$refs.scene
  if (scene) {
    const width = canvas.offsetWidth,
      height = canvas.offsetHeight;

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: canvas,
      antialias: true,
    });
    // [...]
  }
}
```